# Economical difference with high-pressure vessel design pressures for fixed volume

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, materials, structural-analysis

Suppose space is not an issue and I need a fixed volume of compressed air (for storage), say 1m³. Is it more economical to manufacture a thick-walled vessel but with a smaller volume or a thin-walled vessel but with a larger volume? Take into consideration that there will be a valve for filling and releasing too.

Is there some proportional relationship or is it a "it depends" situation with "best of both world" solutions?

Comment: If your valve is already selected that may require a certain thickness just for the connection. If there's nothing else driving the design of the vessel work backwards from that.

Comment: At what pressure should the air be delivered? The higher the pressure needed leads to thicker walls.

Comment: Most economical would be to use the standard compressed gas steel bottles ; lease or purchase. Manifold if you need  more than one .

Comment: @SolarMike 750psi

Answer (score 1):

The scaling for a simple case is easy to calculate. Assume a spherical pressure vessel of radius $r$ and wall thickness $t$ with internal pressure $P$. The stress in the walls scales as $$\frac{Pr}{t}.$$

So, if you double $r$, for the same quantity of gas you reduce $P$ by a factor of 8 (since the internal volume scales as $r^3$), which reduces $t$ by a factor of 4 for the same stress level.

But the walls now cover 4 times as much area, so the amount of material in them is unchanged.

Since big things are generally more expensive to manufacture, handle, and store than small things, small high pressure cylinders probably win.

Comment: Yep, from  basic stress energy point of view, it takes the same amount of steel at a given stress level to contain a given amount of pressurized gas. But welds are priced by the foot ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question is illogic, you said - "Suppose space is not an issue and I need a fixed volume of compressed air (for storage), ...", then ask "Is it more economical to manufacture a thick-walled vessel but **with a smaller volume** or a thin-walled vessel but **with a larger volume**?". And later you responded in the comment that says the pressure is kept constant at 750 psi.

In general, under constant pressure, a larger volume will result in greater hoop tension that would require a thicker wall than the tank with a smaller volume, isn't it? I must have missed something.

Comment: The most reasonable interpretation is that he needs 1 cubic meter of gas at STP; delivered at 750psi. The storage bottle will be higher pressure than that; leading to the question of "how high is most economical". A higher pressure tank is more expensive, but it stores more gas per volume.

Comment: @Drew, how can a gas at STP be at 750 psi?

Comment: @SolarMike That's like saying: "How can natural gas be metered at cubic feet STP if it's delivered at 200psi"

Do you often tell the guys at the welding shop how many moles of co2 you want in the bottle?

Answer (score 0):

The most economical solution would be to parametrically search for the cheapest cylinder that will provide the required volume of gas (when discharged to a minimum pressure of 750 psi, as per your comment).

Realistically the cheapest cylinder design will not be determined by physics constraints, but by economies of scale.